# Difference between the clip-path and shape-outside properties

Tags: css, clip-path

I know that clip-path is used to create a mask on the element, but I'm not sure about the difference between clip-path and shape-outside property and if they can be used together

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to identify the documentation/articles you have looked at and why they didn't help, since this site normally expects you to do your own research before coming here. Does this page https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/ help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both "create invisible layers" but for different purposes.

**clip-path**: It is to "trim" an element creating a mask on top of him that covers the parts that you do not want to show. It does not affect how the elements around it float (they still have a box as reference)

**shape-outside**: Create an invisible layer around the element from which the online elements around it floats (they now have a custom shape as reference). **shape-outside** does not cut out the element or affect how it looks.

[image]
*Note: In this image, you can see how the text floats around the **shape-outside** created (the purple one)*

Both can be used in conjunction perfectly.

**css-shapes-editor** is an amazing extension/tool that can help you work with both properties https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdWsBZiGiZc

Answer (score 1):

The CSS shape-outside properties define what happens around an element, while the clip-path applies to that element.

So if you have a div element it is by default a block (rectangular or square depending). You can apply a border radius of 50% to the div and that would make it round but any elements around the circular div would still appear like a box. If you wanted the text to follow the curves of the circle you would need to apply shape-outside properties to the div.

The clip-path properties prevents certain areas of an element from being displayed instead of showing the complete area.

In Theory you could use them together depending on the result you are trying to achieve.

circle Div showing how elements next to it do not flow around the circle

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div id="circle"></div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
         Maxime illum iure ab minus. Fugiat necessitatibus consequatur 
          eos minus quo, tempora iusto ratione magnam quidem voluptate 
          molestiae minima dignissimos iste facere? 
      </p>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
#circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
   border-radius: 50%;
   }

.wrapper{
   width: 300px;
 }
```

Element showing how text flows around the circle.

```
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="circle"></div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
           Maxime illum iure ab minus. Fugiat necessitatibus consequatur 
           eos minus quo, tempora iusto ratione magnam quidem voluptate 
           molestiae minima dignissimos iste facere? 
         </p>
      </div>
```

The CSS

```
.wrapper{
  width: 300px;
 }


.circle {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: #7db9e8;
   margin: 0 25px 5px 0;
   float: left;
   -webkit-shape-outside: circle();
   shape-outside: circle();
 }
```